# Copy a specific column to a csv in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV files : CSV1 and CSV2 like that :

```
$csv1 :       

School                         Class     
---------                      ----------
School1                        C1
School2                        c2
School3                        c3

$csv2 :

FullName                      
---------                      
Fullname1
Fullname2
Fullname3
```

I use :

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv C:\Tools\csv1.csv 
$csv2 = Import-Csv C:\Tools\csv2.csv
```

But then I'm totally lost how to copy csv2 in csv1 to have something like :

```
School                         Class             FullName                      
---------                      ----------        ---------                      
School1                        C1                Fullname1
School2                        c2                Fullname2
School3                        c3                Fullname3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create list of PSCustomObjects from both files.
So, if you are absolutely (and I mean **ABSOLUTELY**) sure that rows will be properly matched between files you can do something like:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv C:\Tools\csv1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv C:\Tools\csv2.csv
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]@()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $csv1.Count; $i++) {
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        School = $csv1[$i].School
        Class = $csv1[$i].Class
        Fullname = $csv2[$i].FullName
    }
    
    $list.Add($obj)
}

Write-Output $list
```

And result:

```
School  Class Fullname
------  ----- --------
School1 C1    Fullname1
School2 c2    Fullname2
School3 c3    Fullname3
```